# Graphics card runnig at 8X instead of 16X

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, graphics

I have a problem with my graphics card (MSI R9 280X). When I enter BIOS on my PC it say that my graphics card is running at 8X instead of 16X.

I know that the graphics card should be as close as possible to the processor, but when I do that the PC doesn't boot at all.

I have a msi z87-G45 Gaming motherboard and an Intel I5 4670X processor. I run Windows 8.

Comment: You have placed the card in a PCE-E x8 slot its working as it should in that slot.  More information required other then "it does not work" when its in the PCE-X x16 slot

Comment: Check your BIOS. Most likely you have the pcie bus on auto or set to 8x. Sometimes the pcie slot you put it in can also operate at only 8x. Adding other cards can also make a pcie bus operate at only 8x.

Comment: Proximity to the CPU means ***nothing***, you are making an invalid generalization. Consult your motherboard's manual to locate PCIe slots with 16 lanes; they are sometimes colored differently though even that is a bad assumption to make.